# The following code doesn't work .. why?

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, io

The following code isn't working as expected ..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct dest
{
    char filename[20], keyword[20];
    bool opened;
    FILE * stream;
};


void display_data(const struct dest p) {
    printf("Keyword: %s, Filename: %s, Used: %s\n", p.keyword, p.filename, p.opened ? "Yes" : "No");
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // float lon, lat;
    // char info[80];

    if ((argc+1) % 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file_to_read file_for_unknown type file type file ...\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }

    if (access(argv[1], F_OK) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File can't be accessed: %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    const short pairs = (argc-3)/2;
    struct dest data[pairs];

    short times = 4;
    for(short i = 4; i < argc; i += 2) {
        struct dest data[i-times];
        data[i-times].opened = false;
        strcpy(data[i-times].keyword, argv[i-1]);
        strcpy(data[i-times].filename, argv[i]);
        // display_data(data[i-times]);
        times += 1;
    }

    display_data(data[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

That's what happens when I try to run it ..

> ./categorize spooky.csv other.csv UFO UFOS.csv
>   Keyword: ?, Filename: �@, Used: No

Which isn't that meaningful ..
I have been trying to work out the solution .. in vein ..
I don't understand where the problem is ..

Arguments are parsed as follows:

> **The first argument**: the file the program is supposed to read from (ignored for now)
>   **The second argument**: the file the program is supposed to store at any unknown info found in the *spooky.csv file* (also, ignored in this implementation)
>   **The other arguments**: they are parsed as pairs, the first is the keyword, the second is the file ..

My Solution for this filtering problem was to create an array of structs, and within each struct I store the keyword, the filename and the file io stream (which i am ignoring, for now) ..

Any help would be highly appreciated ..

Comment: Why `if ((argc+1) % 2)` instead of `if (argc != NUM_ARGS_EXPECTED)`?  It would be more clear.

Comment: @FiddlingBits because it should accept as many arguments as possible as long as they are pairs starting from the second argument ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 `struct dest data[]` arrays.  The inner one is masking the outer - get rid of it.

Your compiler is probably warning about this, if you have warnings turned on.

Comment: So ... how do I declare an array element as a struct ?

Comment: @AmrAyman: FWIW, I've taken your code, removed the second declaration of data, compiled and ran it on my system (`gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror` on SLES 10), and it produces the expected output; I did not get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @JohnBode Thank you, here is the code I tried and raised Segmentation Fault:


    data[0].opened = false;
    strcpy(data[0].keyword, argv[4]);
    strcpy(data[0].filename, argv[5]);
    printf("Keyword: %s, Filename: %s, Used: %s\n", data[0].keyword, data[0].filename, data[0].opened ? "Yes" : "No");